# Spring Cloud Gateway : disable default routes

Tags: spring, routes, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm using spring cloud to manage my microservices.

For security reasons, for one specific microservice (name it ms_secure), I want to use custom route choose a specific microservice version depending on client IP.

My gateway config looks like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
      routes:
        - id: ms_secure_v1
          uri: lb://ms_secure_v1
          predicates:
            - Path=/ms_secure/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/ms_secure/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
            - name: <my filter>
              args:
                xForwardedForHeaderName: X-Forwarded-For
                hosts:
                  - <IP1>
                  - <IP2>

        - id: ms_secure
          uri: lb://ms_secure_v2
          predicates:
            - Path=/ms_secure/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/ms_secure/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
            - name: <my filter>
              args:
                xForwardedForHeaderName: X-Forwarded-For
                hosts:
                  - <IP3>
                  - <IP4>
```

When when requesting /ms_secure:

- IP1 and IP2 will be redirected to ms_secure_v1
- IP3 and IP4 will be redirected to ms_secure_v2

My problem is that all my clients will also be able to access directly ms_secure_v1 or ms_secure_v2 by using the default routes:

> http:///ms_secure_v1/...
>
> http:///ms_secure_v2/...

I tried to disable these routes by using SetStatus GatewayFilter:

```
        - id: setstatusstring_route
          uri: lb://ms-gateway
          predicates:
            - Path=/ms_secure_v**
          filters:
          - SetStatus=403
```

But this route is not matched.

Is there a way to disable these default routes in spring gateway?

Comment: Why do your have discovery locator as true?

Comment: @spencergibb I thought setting this property to false would solve my problem, but it does not seem to change anything. What is the purpose of this property?

Comment: To create routes dynamically based on services registered in discovery. There are no default routes otherwise. So looking at your routes the predicates are the same `Path=/ms_secure/**`. So it will always match the first one.

Comment: It won't always match the first one because of the filter which will choose the right route depending on source IP. About discovery locator, I don't understand because I disabled it and default routes still match

Comment: Predicates have to match before filters are run.

Comment: Both ms_secure_v1 and ms_secure_v2 should match ms_secure_v**, but they don't

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: Anyway, my question is not about filtering, this part works. My question is about disabling default routes. The first part is just to explain why I want to disable default routes.

Comment: There are no default routes, that's what I'm trying to understand

Comment: http://<gateway>/<microservice name> routes to the microservice, without having declared this route, that's why I'm talking about "default routes", maybe I'm not using the right word. I'm trying to disable this routing.

Comment: After some tests, your first answer was right : setting gateway discovery locator to false solved the problem. I used actuator refresh to validate changes, but it was not enough, and I needed to stop and start gateway. Post it as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following creates routes in gateway based on services registered:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
```

Set it to false (which is the default), if you don't want this.